# listview on arrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem on displaying my list using listview arrayadapter.  My list suppose to have 20 element, but the list will display first 3 and the rest is a repeat of first 3.  However, If i want to fix that, what i can do is to treat convertView always be null, ie. I do not check if convertView ==null. always load new a list for convertView. That way I can get full list, but the list view become very laggy. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    Bitmap bitmapLeft = null;
    Bitmap bitmapRight = null;   //not in used

    Log.d("promo adapter ", "********************getView*************************** ");

    pos=position;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.vicki_listview_row3, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imgLeft = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgLeft);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.imgLeft.setTag(list.get(position)+"left");

        viewHolder.txtMerchantName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.txtEarn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEarn);
        viewHolder.txtExp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewExp);
        viewHolder.imgShare = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgShare);


        viewHolder.txtMerchantName.setText(list.get(position).getMerchantName());
        viewHolder.txtEarn.setText(list.get(position).getDetails());
        viewHolder.txtExp.setText("Exp: " + list.get(position).getStartDateFormat());

        viewHolder.imgShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                MyUtils.openFacebook(context, v, list.get(pos).getCoverPicURL());

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Share button clicked detected",
                //         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });




        try{
            bitmapLeft = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(list.get(position).getImageURL()).getContent());


        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

        //display images
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        if(list.get(position).getImageURL().equals("")){
            //do nothing
            Log.d("Adapter", "*************** Do Nothing*************");
        }
        else {
            if (bitmapLeft!=null)
                holder.imgLeft.setImageBitmap(bitmapLeft);


        }



    }
    else{
        view = convertView;
    }


    return view;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView txtMerchantName;
    protected ImageView imgLeft;
    protected TextView txtEarn;
    protected TextView txtExp;      
    protected ImageView imgShare;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not re-configuring the views that Android is trying to recycle for you. Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    Bitmap bitmapLeft = null;
    Bitmap bitmapRight = null;   //not in used

    Log.d("promo adapter ", "********************getView*************************** ");

    pos=position;

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.vicki_listview_row3, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imgLeft = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgLeft);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.imgLeft.setTag(list.get(position)+"left");

        viewHolder.txtMerchantName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.txtEarn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEarn);
        viewHolder.txtExp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewExp);
        viewHolder.imgShare = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgShare);
    }
    else{
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.txtMerchantName.setText(list.get(position).getMerchantName());
    viewHolder.txtEarn.setText(list.get(position).getDetails());
    viewHolder.txtExp.setText("Exp: " + list.get(position).getStartDateFormat());

    viewHolder.imgShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyUtils.openFacebook(context, v, list.get(pos).getCoverPicURL());
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Share button clicked detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    try{
        bitmapLeft = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(list.get(position).getImageURL()).getContent());
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(list.get(position).getImageURL().equals("")){
        //do nothing
        Log.d("Adapter", "*************** Do Nothing*************");
    }
    else {
        if (bitmapLeft!=null)
            viewHolder.imgLeft.setImageBitmap(bitmapLeft);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, same result as what I have said on my question, it will show full list, but the scrolling of the list a big laggy.

Answer (score 0):

use  if (convertView == null) condition only to inflate your views and to make objects to your ui elements ..do all other operations out of that condition.

Comment: can you be more specific?  How to " make objects to your ui elements ..do all other operations out of that condition", do I need to refresh my listview when user scroll down the listview?